# Installing Ant, JDK & JRE on CentOS7, after that still having problems with launching .bat files

Tags: java, linux, batch-file, ant, centos7

I ve installed JDK + JRE:

```
# cd /opt
# wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u45-b14/jdk-8u45-linux-x64.rpm"
# wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u45-b14/jre-8u45-linux-x64.rpm"

# rpm -Uvh jdk-8u45-linux-x64.rpm
# rpm -Uvh jre-8u45-linux-x64.rpm

# export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_72
Setup JRE_HOME Variable
# export JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_72/jre
Setup PATH Variable
# export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_72/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_72/jre/bin
```

Then I did installation of the Ant:

```
# cd /opt
# wget https://www.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.6-bin.tar.gz
ln -s /opt/ant/bin/ant /usr/bin/ant
vi /etc/profile.d/ant.sh
```

Add the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
ANT_HOME=/opt/ant
PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH ANT_HOME
export CLASSPATH=.

chmod +x /etc/profile.d/ant.sh
source /etc/profile.d/ant.sh
```

After that Im trying to lauch my .bat but still have this message:

```
./startLoginServer.bat



./startLoginServer.bat: line 1: @echo: command not found
./startLoginServer.bat: line 2: title: command not found
./startLoginServer.bat: line 4: :start: command not found
Starting Login Server.
./startLoginServer.bat: line 6: echo.: command not found
./startLoginServer.bat: line 8: REM: command not found
Error: Unable to locate JRE meeting specification "1.8"
./startLoginServer.bat: line 31: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I know its saying I dont have proper JRE. But I did installed it. Im quite lost here guys. Please, help a bit if you can. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.bat` files are meant for Windows operating system. There should some `.sh` files for the Linux flavors. Check it out !!